# What prevents using .bashrc to initialize Terminal?

Tags: terminal, bash, path

A few months ago, I made it easier to run scripts I'd written by creating a .bashrc file.  It worked for a while, but it has not worked in a few weeks.  As the Terminal snippet below shows, the file apparently does not run when Terminal is launched.   I haven't changed anything that should affect this.  Is there a Terminal preference that non-intuitively has this effect?  Does use of 'homebrew' override?

```
MBP-WWG:~ Admin$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
MBP-WWG:~ Admin$ ls -late@ .bashrc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Admin  staff  45 Jul 29 14:35 .bashrc
MBP-WWG:~ Admin$ cat !$
cat .bashrc

export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
export $path=$PATH

MBP-WWG:~ Admin$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
MBP-WWG:~ Admin$ echo $path

MBP-WWG:~ Admin$
```

Comment: You should be using `.bash_profile`  Also see:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119627/why-are-interactive-shells-on-osx-login-shells-by-default/119675#119675

Comment: Well, that detailed discussion tells how to get around the problem, but doesn't explain why it worked for a little while and than quit.

Comment: Terminal.app > Preferences>Profiles>Shell>Startup>Run command could cause bashrc to be read. I suggest you read the bash manual under the heading INVOCATION. BTW, where did you define `$path`?

Comment: export $path= was an error; should have been export path=

Comment: The "run comand" was off, and I had never changed it (until now).  The command was blnk but when I checked the box, it was auto-filled with "-bash"  Since the other method already got things working, I turned this off again.  I use MacOS man pages but I don't trust them.  I've already found some copied from other unixes without having Apple's changes edited in.

Comment: Is there another issue here besides the `export $path=$PATH` error?